# How big are the automated lockers at the St Charles station in Marseilles?

Tags: luggage-storage, marseille

There are automated lockers at St Charles, how big are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 7.5EUR for 24hrs middle size is big enough for a Firelite 69/25 suitcase with the second shortest edge vertical and a Red Oxx XS Aviator with the longest edge vertical. It's a squeeze but it fits.

Edit: so about 35" deep, 20" high and 13" wide.

Comment: That's certainly precise but a rough height/length/depth measurement could perhaps help others generalize more easily?

Comment: Firelite 69/25: (LxWxH) 18.5 x 11.4 x 27.2 inches; 47cm x 29cm x 69cm - Red Oxx XS Aviator: (LxWxH) 15" x 8" x 11" inches; 38.1cm x 20.3cm x 27.9cm